# How to make a Hyperledger Blockchain application public/Online?

Tags: angular, ibm-cloud, blockchain, cloudant

As I have seen the tutorials, I did watch the 6 videos that IBM afford and I did read all the Docs at ( https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/develop_starter.html#deploying-a-business-network ) Sadly, even by following everything step by step on a freshly formatted machine, I do still get errors no matter what. I would like to have some assistance in setting up this task if possible as it's the first time I work on IBM related services.

**The current state is :** I have a business network well developped and works perfectly fine on my local Hyperledger Composer. All the assets and everything is working fine.

**The issue is :** I need help in order to make a working blockchain either with my starter plan or with only a Kubernetes Clusters where people can access the generated angular application on internet, see and make changes on that application which will controle the blockchain network which will be possibly installed on an IBM Kubernete Cluster or Cloud depends on what would work in this case.

May I have some help in making this happen and be guided through the process to make because I couldn't find the correct approach already tested and working properly to fill my needs? As I will of course upgrade to entreprise plan and spend on the cloud (or Cluster) as much as needed once i do have a working stable concept that works.

Thank you in advance for all the help and service

Comment: This is a forum for developing applications, and for further actions please post logs relevant to your issue here.

Answer (score 0):

@d0bry
I found out that the version wasn't the matching one
and I could follow up the whole tutorial as now my code works on IBM StarterPlan Blockchain deployed.
After trying to follow this tutorial https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/vehicle-manufacture
with my own business network, when before trying to push the application using the files in your clone of this repository, I generated the app via Yeoman and it displayed for me this log when i tried to npm start:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/hiro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/hiro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.0
3 info using node@v8.11.4
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
4 verbose stack     at run (/home/hiro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at /home/hiro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at /home/hiro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:115:5
4 verbose stack     at /home/hiro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:418:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (/home/hiro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:373:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (/home/hiro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:416:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (/home/hiro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:160:5)
4 verbose stack     at /home/hiro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:280:12
4 verbose stack     at /home/hiro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)
5 verbose cwd /home/hiro/Documents/medcretech-network
6 verbose Linux 4.15.0-33-generic
7 verbose argv "/home/hiro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node" "/home/hiro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/npm" "start"
8 verbose node v8.11.4
9 verbose npm  v6.4.0
10 error missing script: start
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

is there a way to fix this up? or i don't have to npm start in order to make my blockchain on the IBM cloudant